# solve clang-12 overloaded-virtual warning

Tags: c++, clang++

The code below gives a clang-12 warning:

```
warning: 'foo::TIFFFormat::encodePixels' hides overloaded virtual function [-Woverloaded-virtual]
```

What can I do to solve the problem described by this warning ?

```
namespace foo {

struct bar {
    int k;
};

class IImageFormat
{
  public:
    virtual ~IImageFormat() = default;
    virtual bool encodePixels(void) = 0;
    virtual bool encodePixels(bar pixels) = 0;
};



class ImageFormat : public IImageFormat
{
  public:
    bool encodePixels(bar pixels) override;

};


bool ImageFormat::encodePixels(bar pixels){
    (void)pixels;
    return false;
}


class TIFFFormat : public ImageFormat
{
  public:
    bool encodePixels() override;
};

bool TIFFFormat::encodePixels(){
    return false;
}

}


foo::TIFFFormat tf;
```

Comment: Does "fix" mean "hide the warning message" or "solve the problem described by the warning"?

Comment: @DrewDormann thanks - I can suppress it with pragmas, but I want to solve the problem instead.

Comment: Why doesn't `TIFFFormat` implement `encodePixels(bar pixels)`?

Comment: ... and adding that implementation will kill the warning.

Comment: Thanks - it uses the parent implementation - doesn't need to implement it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring one of the two overloads in the derived class, but not the other, will cause name lookup from the derived class to find only the one declared in the derived class.

So with your code you will not be able to call e.g. `tf.encodePixels(foo::bar{})`.

If you don't want to repeat all overloads in the derived class, you can import all of them via a `using` declaration in `TIFFFormat`:

```
using ImageFormat::encodePixels;
```

If you don't care or intent the overload to not be reachable from the derived class, then the warning is not relevant to you.